# Count and records from yesterday and add datecolumn next to it with yesterday's date in Bigquery, standardSQL

Tags: date, count, google-bigquery

I've been able to get a sql running where I grab the count of all records from the day before.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM mytable
WHERE date(ingest_time) >= (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND
      date(ingest_time) < (CURRENT_DATE());
```

Adding to the SQL above in Bigquery, how do I generate a date column next to it that shows that these records are from yesterday with the date.

Something like this:

1) 3000390 | 2019-11-13

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `SELECT count(*)` use `SELECT count(*), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`